# AWS API Gateway: REST API vs HTTP API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

What is the difference between AWS API Gateway REST API vs HTTP API? Why would you use one over the other. What different functionalities does each support?

The documentation says:

> API Gateway REST API A collection of HTTP resources and methods that
> are integrated with backend HTTP endpoints, Lambda functions, or other
> AWS services.........Each API resource can expose one or more API
> methods that have unique HTTP verbs supported by API Gateway.
>
> API Gateway HTTP API A collection of routes and methods that are
> integrated with backend HTTP endpoints or Lambda functions....Each route can expose
> one or more API methods that have unique HTTP verbs supported by API
> Gateway.

However I cannot make much sense out of this.

Answer (score 4):

According to their [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-api-gateway-offers-faster-cheaper-simpler-apis-using-http-apis-preview/) from 2019, they're stating the following:

> HTTP APIs are up to 71% cheaper compared to REST APIs, but offer only API proxy functionality.

So it seems you can't use the HTTP api's for anything other than proxying your own backend API.

Additionally, check [this comprehensive documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html) on when to use one over the other.